# Javascript Ajax success image replace

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I have problem.

That code should change image on site after success or error:

[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/WwsEb0Pu)

```
if(isset($func) and $func == 'claim_bonus'){
global $ado;
$user = escape($_GET['user']);
$type = escape($_GET['type']);
$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$points = rand(1,20);

$query = $ado->exec("INSERT INTO `claimed_bonuses` SET `user` = '$user', `date` = '$now', `type` = '$type'");
$query1 = $ado->exec("INSERT INTO `history` SET `user` = '$user', `date` = '$now', `type` = 'bonus', `amount` = '$points', `title` = 'Bonus Claimed', `description` = '$user claimed bonus $points points'");
$query2 = $ado->exec("update `balances` SET `actual` = actual+$points, `total` = total+$points");


if ($query && $query1 && $query2) { 
echo "<img src=\"/img/bonus/add_used.png\" width=\"30%\" height=\"30%\" alt=\"Bonus claimed\" />";
    } else {
    echo "<img src=\"/img/bonus/error.png\" width=\"30%\" height=\"30%\" alt=\"Error\" />";
    }
```

}

Im calling ajax using [ajax.js file](http://pastebin.com/Gjy6RnBk)

```
// JavaScript Document
var xmlhttp=false;


function claimbonus(user, type, id){
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xmlhttp.abort();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "/functions/ajax.php?func=claim_bonus&user="+user+"&type="+type, true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
    xmlhttp.send(null);  
}
```

And code is loaded on page.

Script is returning image but it doesnt replace old image.

Image code:

```
<img src="img/bonus/add.png" width="30%" height="30%" alt="Claim bonus" id="add_img" onclick="claimbonus(<?php echo $_SESSION['userid']; ?>, '<?php echo $type; ?>', 'add_img'); return false"/>
```

I hope someone can help me

Comment: Please add your code to the actual question rather than linking to it. You should also reduce your code as much as possible to a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), and try and debug as much as possible yourself and tell us which parts of your code do(n't) work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for information on creating good questions that are likely to receive good answers. Please consider updating your question to include relevant snippets of code along with complete descriptions of what you expect to happen, what is happening now, and what you have tried.

Comment: please take a look at the JQuery libaray it has a nice and easy way to handle Ajax requests

Comment: try console.log(xmlhttp.responseText) and make sure it is returning what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the innerHTML of the image tag. Wrap in a div or span and replace that instead and quote the userid too

```
<span id="add_img"><img 
src="img/bonus/add.png" width="30%" height="30%" 
alt="Claim bonus" 
onclick="claimbonus('<?php echo $_SESSION['userid']; ?>', 
'<?php echo $type; ?>', 'add_img')/></span>
```